# Imaginary numbers

Tags: java, math, complex-numbers, quadratic

I have a method that takes 3 `double`s and calculates the roots via the Quadratic Formula:

```
public static double[] quadraticFormula(double a, double b, double c) throws ArithmeticException {
    double root1 = 0;
    double root2 = 0;

    //sqrt(b^2 - 4ac)
    double discriminant = (b * b) - (4 * a * c);

    if (Double.isNaN(discriminant)) {
        throw new ArithmeticException(discriminant + " is not a number!");
    }

    if (discriminant > 0) {
        //Two roots
        root1 = (-b + Math.sqrt(discriminant)) / (2 * a);
        root2 = (-b - Math.sqrt(discriminant)) / (2 * a);
    } else if (discriminant == 0) {
        //One root
        root1 = (-b + Math.sqrt(discriminant)) / (2 * a);
    } else if (discriminant < 0) {
        //Imaginary roots
    }

    return new double[] { root1, root2 };
}
```

I want to expand on this and add support for imaginary numbers. How would I accomplish this? My first thought was, in `else if (discriminant < 0)`, I would get the absolute value of the discriminant and factor the radical. I am going to output the roots to the user, so don't bother with the *i*, I have a String parser that knows exactly where to put the *i*. Any ideas on a more efficient method?

Comment: The formula is much the same except that you multiply discriminant by -1 before sqrting it and then this is the imaginary part to the -b/2a being the real part. I doubt you are going to get a better method without using a real complex number class. And the code then should be pretty simple but may be less efficient because a complex number class may end up doing much more stuff than you need in this simple example.

Comment: This is a minor comment that is not directly related to your question. Your method may return {0d, 0d}, but the caller would not know if it is returning 2, 1, or 0 real roots. If you used Double instead of double, then you could initialize them to null. The contract would then be to return real roots as doubles and imaginary roots as nulls. (Of course, when you return a complex number, you will avoid this problem of representation.)

Comment: @rajah9 I do checks to the array in the class that calls this method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to get going on Complex/Imaginary numbers I would suggest to implement a class that represents a complex number.

An example for that can be found here:
http://www.math.ksu.edu/~bennett/jomacg/c.html

If you somehow build your calculations of a mixture of doubles, arrays and strings it will definetely get messy after a while.

Comment: Precisely what I was writing. This is not very object-oriented is it?

Comment: @Mauro: It doesn't feel object oriented because you have a procedural version of quadraticFormula. The problem isn't that making a complex number class isn't very object-oriented. You could have a Number class (of which ComplexNumber would be a subtype), and use it in a Polynomial class. Then Polynomial could have `List<Number> getRoots()`. You'd construct the polynomial and ask for its roots. This would be object oriented, yes? It would also be quite a hassle. But no, the non-object-oriented part isn't the complex number class.